# How to easily rewrap extracted part of HTML into new document

Tags: html, perl, xhtml, xml-twig

I use the XML::Twig Perl module to extract a div out of an HTML document, and would like to create a new HTML doc containing only this div, and the required HTML wrapping. I would then also add some CSS styles to the new document.

Extracting the div is easy, but I'm too lazy to write the HTML wrapping around it myself :-).

There surely must be a Perl module which would do that boring part for me. Or maybe even a method in XML::Twig itself, which I overlooked or didn't understand?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to create a (very, very!) minimal HTML twig by using `my $html= XML::Twig->new->parse_html( '')` and then paste your div in it. You may want to`replace the empty string by something a little more HTML-y though, or even load a better HTML template, which could have the CSS in it too.

Comment: Thank you. Works, but is really minimal, and a long way from valid html. I could use CGI.pm's `start_html()`, but a 260+KB module to print half a dozen lines seems very inelegant...